# Swap two numeric variables without unpacking in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, variables, swap

How can I swap two numeric variables without unpacking or define a new variable in python?
I mean not this way:

```
a, b = b, a
```

and not this way:

```
c = a
a = b
b = c
```

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to solve, ot what is your objective.

Comment: @alt-f4 It's my homework.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @alt-f4 I see this too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823

Comment: No one has a problem that you are trying to solve your homework. "It's my homework" is not an objective. Try to provide code examples of expected input and output and further clarification so we can help you answer your question. You only pasted two snippets of code of things that you do not want. That does not help much.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
a = a + b
b = a - b
a = a - b
```

Comment: How do you know they're not strings or complex objects?

Comment: This logic would be applicable only for numeric value's !!

Comment: see [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601)